# pscustomobject multiple lines per row

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory-group, pscustomobject

I have some code so far, but would like it to result in a table with multiple lines for users per group.

Currently, it creates a table like this:

| Group | Users |
| --- | --- |
| abcgroup1 | Alice |
| abcgroup1 | Bob |
| abcgroup2 | Bob |
| abcgroup2 | Jason |
| abcgroup3 | Eve |

I would like it to instead create a table like this:

| Group | Users |
| --- | --- |
| abcgroup1 | Alice Bob |
| abcgroup2 | Bob Jason |
| abcgroup3 | Eve |

```
$Groups = get-adgroup -Filter 'name -like "*abc*"'

$Results = foreach( $Group in $Groups ){

    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | foreach {

        [pscustomobject]@{

            Group = $Group.Name

            Users = $_.Name

            }

        }

    }

$Results

$Results | Export-Csv C:\abc_search.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`-join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_join?view=powershell-7.1) operator concatenating by **CRLF** `` `r`n ``. This will result in a multiline `string`:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter "name -like '*abc*'"
$Results = foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Group = $Group.Name
        Members = (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group).Name -join "`r`n"
    }
}

$Results | Format-Table -Wrap -Autosize
$Results | Export-Csv C:\abc_search.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Note that I'm using `-Wrap` on [`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-7.1), needed to correctly display multiline `strings` on the console.

The other option you could use is `Out-String` thought that would also require the use of `.TrimEnd()` method to get rid of the trailing new line:

```
Members = ((Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group).Name | Out-String).TrimEnd()
```